# Does Firebase node.js admin sdk auto update itself?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

In my front end code, I periodically refer to https://firebase.google.com/support/releases and update my `<head>` tag to include the latest javascript sdk version.  For instance, as of now, we're at version 8.3.1, so:

```
<script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/8.3.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

However, in my back-end code (`index.js` file), there's no place where I explicitly initialize a version number; I simply initialize as follows:

`admin.initializeApp()`

So, I'm wondering:

1. Does the node.js admin sdk auto update itself?
2. Or am I missing a step?
3. If yes to 1., how do I see what version of the node.js admin sdk I'm actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK for Node is usually installed and upgraded through NPM. It does *not* auto-update itself, but you can run a single [update command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-update) to update all the packages listed to the latest version.